# Image not matching parents height and width

Tags: html, css

I have a container div with defined height and width. I have bunch of tables under the container. I want those tables to inherit height and width from the container div. One of these tables *could* have an image and I would like the image to fit and expand the table elastically.

Here is what I tried in `JsFiddle` http://jsfiddle.net/nileshdk/kLLLoxrn/

I thought marking image containing div's height and width 100%; it would inherit those properties from parent div. However it seems that the table is stretched according to the *image width* and not vice versa. Can someone please explain what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `width: 100%` for the images parent element. You need to set it on the image element itself.

```
#screenshot > img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kLLLoxrn/1/